# I can't get this simple regex to work correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing this in Javascript

Here's my string: `09.22.2011-23.21-west-day`

Here's what I'd like to pull out of it: `23.21`

Here's my expression: `/-[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/`

I get `-23.21` so I'd have to run a a replace method after this to remove the "-". Is there a way to leave out the "-" with this regex or not? I never really perfected my regex skills because I usually use PHP which has the nice () capture groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript has [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) too:

```
var time = "09.22.2011-23.21-west-day".match(/-(\d{2}\.\d{2})/)[1]
```

Gives you `23.21`

1. You can use `\d` as a shorthand for `[0-9]`
2. If you know how many digits it's supposed to have, use `{n}` or `{m,n}` quantifiers. It will  reduce the chance of it matching the wrong thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Everyone's answer was perfect. I didn't know that capture groups were called capture groups. This makes everything much easier!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `()` in JavaScript too!

```
s = '09.22.2011-23.21-west-day';
rx = s.match('-([0-9]*\.[0-9]*)')
alert(rx[1]);
```